# LTS 22.04 Issue with the desktop shortcuts

Tags: 22.04, shortcuts

I am trying to add application shortcut to desktop (LTS 22.04) but cannot make it work.
The icon for .desktop file (i.e. firefox.desktop) copied from application folder shortcut has small red ❌ badge and context menu does not have "Allow Launch" option. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To turn it into a working launcher:

1. Right-click the icon on the desktop
2. Select "Allow launching" from the menu that appeared